# Rewrite many URL's to another directory while altering the filenames

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is rewrite something like

`http://www.example.com/folderA/aaa_bb_cc_ddd.php`

to

`http://www.example.com/folderB/aaa-bb.php`

...and I'm have just an awful time figuring out how.  Any help or a point in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really going to depend on what these many URL's look like, but for starters you can try this in your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?folderA/(.*)_cc_ddd\.php /folderB/$1.php [L]
```

The trick here is figuring out what `(.*)_cc_ddd\.php` needs to look like. It's *entirely dependent* on this list of many URL's that you need to alter.